# git push/pull keeps on trying to produce GUI window

Tags: git

Every time I try to do git push or pull on one of our work server I get a "Error: Can't open display:" warning, unless I login with -X forwarding, in which case some ugly 90s looking window pops up for me to type my password in.

Is there any setting to suppress this behaviour? I'm completely stumped and can't find anything on Google...

**Edit:**
The window that pops up when X forwarding is enabled is as shown below:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the desired askpass command using `git config`. The relevant config key is called `core.askpass`.

To change it: `git config --global core.askpass /path/to/command`

The value set in your Git config can be overridden using the `GIT_ASKPASS` environment variable.

If `core.askpass` is not set, it first tries the command defined in the `SSH_ASKPASS` environment variable. Next (and last) in the fallback order is a simple built-in password prompt.

Source and details: [git-config Documentation](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-config) (search for `core.askpass`)

Comment: This did the trick! I don't know what was setting SSH_ASKPASS to some X11 program, but setting it to the empty string in my .bashrc resolved the issue. Many thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like you are using the **pinentry** program to enter your git login password, of which multiple variants exist. In your case, the selected default seems to be pinentry-gtk2, which is indeed ugly as hell. :)

Try your luck with

```
ls -l /usr/bin/pinentry*
```

to see which variants are installed. There will likely be one of the binaries symlinked, which is the "default". You can choose another pinentry program by relinking the symlink, although that may confuse your package manager. Just to see if that is the actual issue, delete the /usr/bin/pinentry symlink or relink it to pinentry-curses to see if the behaviour changes.

Funny thing is that I don't remember git actually using the pinentry program, but gnupg does. Maybe you have some setup involving gpg-agent, SSH keys and effectively GnuPG asking for a passphrase via pinentry?

If you lack privileges to fiddle with the symlink directly, you can try editing the gpg-agent configuration:

```
mkdir -p ~/.gnupg   # may fail if dir already exists
echo 'pinentry-program /usr/bin/pinentry-curses' >> ~/.gnupg/gpg-agent.conf
```

This should instruct the gpg-agent to use the cli-based pinentry-curses program instead. It's a long shot, but worth a try.

Comment: There are indeed several programs there: /usr/bin/pinentry, /usr/bin/pinentry-curses, /usr/bin/pinentry-qt -> pinentry-qt4, and
/usr/bin/pinentry-qt4. I'm not sure why git/gpg-agent is calling these programs, or how to stop it. I don't have root access.

Comment: Added a paragraph about choosing pinentry with gpg-agent. To be perfectly honest, it would be a bit contrived to assume gpg-agent is involved here, but it's at least halfway plausible. To find out what is being run, you could cause the pin entry dialog to appear, and while it is shown, run "ps fauxww" in another shell to have a look at the process list and look for any processes run by your user. One of them ought to have caused this.

Comment: Thanks for the updated suggestion, but it didn't work. I ran fauxww as you suggested, which informs me that git pull call 'git-remote-https origin ...', which in turn calls '/usr/libexec/openssh/x11-ssh-askpass Password:'. I'm guessing this last bit is what causes the window to appear, but I don't know why.